# About generators of a finitely generated ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$. Let $S$ be a subset of $R$, with infinitely many elements. Let $\mathfrak{i}$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $S$. Suppose $\mathfrak{i}$ finitely generated:
$$\mathfrak{i}=Rr_1+\ldots+Rr_n$$
with $r_i\in R$. Can i always find generators $r_i$'s in $S$?

Comment: No, for instance let $S=R\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: @user1 take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{1\}$. Then $\mathfrak{i}=\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}2+\mathbb{Z}3$, with $2,3\in S$

Comment: But also $\mathfrak i = \mathbb Z1$. It seems as though the question you have typed here is not the same as what you want to ask.

Comment: @user1 yes, but my question is: can i find generators in $S$? not: is it every possible generator an element of $S$?

Comment: That would be my error, not yours. Sorry.

Comment: @user1 i've edited to make it more clear

Comment: Write the $r_i$ as a combination of elements of $S$. Then you get a new generating system of elements contained in $S$. Ofcourse  the number of generators $n$ can change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Suppose $I=\lbrace a_1 r_1+\cdots +a_nr_n|a_i\in R\rbrace$, now each $r_i\in I$ implies one can write $r_i=\sum_{j=1}^{n_i} a_{i_j}s_{i_j}$, where $s_{i_j}\in S$. Then we have $I\subseteq\lbrace \sum_{i=1}^ma_i s_i|a_i\in R\rbrace :=J$ for some finite number of $s_j$'s. Also note that $J\subseteq I$, because $I$ is generated by $S$ and so $s\in I$ for each $s\in S$.

Comment: there is a point i can't understand. Why can you write $r_i$ as a combination of $\textrm{finitely}$ many elements of $S$?

Comment: @Federica Maggioni: Because $I$ is generated by $S$ and $r_i\in I$.

Comment: @YACP ops, sorry, it is the set of FINITE linear combinations of elements of the subset with coefficients in the ring, ok, thank you all